# bcp import data into Azure data warehouse

Tags: azure, authentication, import, bcp, azure-synapse

I am trying to import data from a text pipe delimited file to Azure data warehouse using bcp. I have bcp 15.0 version. I have given the following command

bcp dbname.tablename in C:\Documents\Test.txt -t, -F 2 -C ACP -m 9999 -S tcp:servername.database.windows.net -U username@servername -P password  -T -c -t"|"

However, I am getting the following error

SQLState = FA004, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user '' in     Active Directory (Authentication option is 'WindowsIntegrated').
Error code 0xCAA9001F; state 10
Integrated Windows authentication supported only in federation flow.

Please can some one help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `-T` switch means to connect with trusted auth (Integrated Windows auth) prt the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762). Remove this switch.